# Documenting a Python C Extension on ReadTheDocs

Tags: python, python-c-api, read-the-docs

I have a Python package including a couple C extensions whose documentation I would like to host on ReadTheDocs, but the build fails, apparently because the C extensions are not being compiled.  The C extension modules include functions with docstrings that I would like to be included, so simply mocking the C modules is not a solution.

RTD says their build procedure can't compile arbitrary C code, but they also include some basic C libraries in their environment, and my package only has C-standard includes. Alternately, the package is hosted on PyPI with a wheels distribution, is there a way for RTD to grab the necessary modules from there?